# Удалить содержимое html тега

Tags: javascript

Здравствуйте.
Каким образом можно удалить содержимое html тега на javascript?

Т.е. у меня есть функция:

```
<html>
<script>
function ttt(url) {
...
здесь код для удаления из текста содержимого тегов <div id="id123"> </div>
}
</script>
<body>
<div id="id123"><a href="#" onclick="ttt('site')">текст</a></div> привет
</body>
</html>
```

Суть моей задачи в том, чтобы по окончанию выполнения функции ttt, содержимое тега <div id="id123"> </div> удалялось.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

.

```
element.innerText = '';
// or
element.innerHTML = ''

// jq
element.text('');
// or
element.html('');
```

Comment: спасибо, помогло.

Comment: Та ладно? Правда помогло? =)